# Summernote showing html markup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, summernote

I'm having some problem with Summernote, in a Rails application. I have attached it to a text area, and can successfully create a marked-up document using the **new** method and form. Then I can display the marked up document using a **simple_format**.

But when I **edit** the document, the markup is shown in the document as text, see attached image. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Code used for both new and edit:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :article %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :article_body, input_html: { class: 'summernote' } %>
    </div>
    <%= f.input :status, collection: enum_option_pairs(Article, :status) %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Code used for show:

```
  <%= simple_format(@article.article_body) %>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.summernote').summernote({
    height: 120
   });
 });
```

Summernote Rails gem: https://github.com/summernote/summernote-rails

Comment: After the create/save the content is probably saved as html to the database. Maybe you have to use `raw` output on the inputfield.

Comment: Yes it is saved as html. Both raw & html_safe made no difference.

Comment: I ended up going with Bootsy instead https://github.com/volmer/bootsy

Comment: That's odd. But glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you need in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.summernote').summernote({
    height: 120
   });
```

> if is edit

```
$(".summernote").summernote("code", your server variable to string);

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

simply adds the methode sanitize before calling the variable.
example to display course with the applied style:

```
<%= sanitize @course.corps %>
```

credit for: https://gorails.com/episodes/trix-editor

Answer (score 0):

If you using textarea or input, you can directly put the value as bellow. Here i using textarea as summernote node.

```
<textarea id="summernote" name="content">
  <%- locals.data.content %>
</textarea>
```